# How to determine if fgets stopped before all letters were read?

Tags: c, file, fgets

I do something like this:

```
char buf[100];              
int n = 0;                  
char save[100][100];        

while (fgets(buf,100, file)!=NULL) {
    strcpy(save[n], buf);
    printf("%s",buf);
    n++;
}
```

I opened a `FILE = *file` with error handling before. 
I only want to read the lines that have less than or equal to 100 characters. Those that feature more characters, I want to ignore and write some special message to the "save" array or to the `perror` or `stout` stream.

However, how can I possibly know whether I got exactly 100 characters or my `fgets` has simply stopped reading at its limit?

How can I know whether I got more than 100 in the first place?

Comment: You could read up to 101 characters, and if you got 101, then you have more than 100!

Comment: If you want to read (and print) n chars you need a: char buffer[n+1]; if you declare char buffer[102] you can read 101 char and check the length. If it's 101 and the last char is a newline you have read exactly 100 char (remove the newline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us assume that `fgets()` is not going to read a null character. If it does, the following method may be insufficient.

> I only want to read the lines that have less than or equal to 100 characters. Those that feature more characters, I want to ignore and write some special message to the "save" array

Problem 1.  Is the `'\n'` or <kbd>Enter</kbd> part of the *100 characters*?  Let us assume it is not.

OP appears to still  want to *read* the line, be it longer or shorter than 100 or `COLS` characters, it is just a question of what to do with it then.

Recommend a buffer of `COLS+3`.  One for the null character, one for the `'\n'` and one for extra long line detection.

```
#define ROWS 100
#define COLS 100
char save[ROWS][COLS+1];  // +1 for \0      
char buf[COLS + 3];              
int n = 0;                  

while (n < ROWS && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file)!=NULL) {
  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  bool EOLorEOFfound = false;

  // lop off potential \n
  if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
    buf[--len] = '\0';
    EOLorEOFfound = true;
  }

  // if line is too long ...
  if (len > COLS) {
    // consume rest of line
    while (!EOLorEOFfound) {
      int ch = fgetc(file);
      EOLorEOFfound = ch == '\n' || ch == EOF;
    }
    // write some special message to the "save" array
    assert(COLS >= 3);
    strcpy(save[n], "***");
  } 
  // Line not too long
  else {
    strcpy(save[n], buf);  // or memcpy(save[n], buf, len+1);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
  }
  n++;
}
```

Comment: though i more or less agree with your answer, would you mind to explain the expression from  `if (len > COLS)`  furhter? I do not understand why you declare ch as an int and also i dont get what the expression in the line that follows `int ch == fgetc(stdin)` means. And, why even the double _is equal_ sign?

Comment: actually i dont get the whole "consume rest of line" part

Comment: found your mistake: `int ch == fgetc(stdin)` has 2 mistakes in it.

Comment: @Josch Kraus  The code `if (len > COLS)` tests as the above comment "if line is too long ...".  You want lines that are too long to be detected, that is what the `if()` detects.  `ch` is declared as an `int` as that is the type returned by `fgetc()`.  The function returns values in the range `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Using a `char` is problematic.  the `==` should have been `=`.  Aside from the `==` part, what problem do you see with `int ch = fgetc(stdin)`.

Comment: it must be file, not stdin

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `fgets()`, [use `getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html).  With `fgets()`, once you read a too-long line (however you identify it), you'll have to keep reading that line and discarding it until you reach a new line.  In other words, you have a need to track state, which isn't needed if you use `getline()` since it gives you the entire line, and tells you how long it is:

```
FILE *fp = // fopen() however you need to

char *lineArray[ MAX_LINES ];
int ii = 0;

char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0UL;

// loop until getline() fails
for ( ;; )
{
    ssize_t lineLen = getline( &line, &len, fp );
    if ( lineLen == -1L )
    {
        break;
    }

    if ( lineLen > 100L )
    {
        // handle too-long line
    }
    else
    {
        lineArray[ ii ] = strdup( line );
        ii++;
    }
}
```

You might want to strip any trailing `newline` characters from each line before copying the line to the array.

Note that I used `strdup()` to copy the line - that's not a C Standard function, [but it is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

Comment: Detail: `getline()` is also not a C standard function.  `getline()` does oblige memory allocation of the very ling line.  I see this as a concern only if the input may be [hostile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_exhaustion_attack).

Answer (score 0):

You could check the string length and the last character. If the length is `99` characters and the last character is not a newline, then there are more characters on the line that `fgets` didn't read (though the remaining characters might just be the newline).

If `fgets` read the whole line, either the length of the string will be less than `99` or the last character will be a newline (which `fgets` always adds if it fits in the buffer).

Note that I say *99* characters, as an array of 100 character will only fit 99 characters plus the string terminator character `'\0'`. If you want to read up to (and including) 100 characters, your buffer needs to be 101 characters large.

[Example showing it in "action"](http://ideone.com/6ZPXs0). The first two outputs is from reading lines that are longer, and `fgets` didn't read all of the line. The second two lines of output are when `fgets` read the whole lines.

Comment: NMDV: yet "If the length is 99 characters and the last character is not a newline, then there are more characters on the line that fgets didn't read" may not be true when reading the last line of a file.  Similar issue with "If fgets read the whole line, either the length of the string will be less than 99 ...".  A file that does not end with `'\n'` is a bother.

Comment: i think you answer is great and easy, if there was a way to handle the issue that @chux has mentioned that would be great and easy