# How does the sequence of execution determined when multiple operators are involved?

Tags: c, syntax, variable-assignment, logical-operators

```
while (!EOLorEOFfound) {
      int ch == fgetc(stdin);
      EOLorEOFfound = ch == '\n' || ch == EOF;
}
```

Note: `EOLorEOFfound` is of type bool.

I was given this answer by a StackOverFlow user concerning another problem. See here:

[How to determine if fgets stopped before all letters were read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867754/how-to-determine-if-fgets-stopped-before-all-letters-were-read)

Now, i have been puzzeling what the expression in the last line of code actually does. I suspect it is some form of the ternary operator maybe?

Comment: `int ch == fgetc(stdin);` is probably a bug, should be `int ch = fgetc(stdin);` (`=` instead of `==`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence),

- `==` has highest priority,
- `||` is second highest
- `=` is least.

So,

```
EOLorEOFfound = ch == '\n' || ch == EOF;
```

is the same as

```
EOLorEOFfound = ( (ch == '\n') || (ch == EOF) );
```

So all it does is, compare `ch` against the given values, and then, assign the result in `EOLorEOFfound`.

FWIW, point to note, the result of the logical OR (`||`) is of type `int`.

Answer (score 7):

```
EOLorEOFfound = ch == '\n' || ch == EOF;
```

does the same as

```
EOLorEOFfound = (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF);
```

that is, assigning the result of a boolean expression to a variable. No magic here.

Comment: You are right, no magic. Thanks for a clear and simple answer.